# JDK 1.4 compilation error

Tags: java

My code is perfectly fine in JDK 1.6, but when I complile it in JDK 1.4 i get errrors

Code is

```
  public void generateSection(long parId, long splId, long ogrId) throws    DBUexecuteQueryException, DBUqueryParameterException, DBUcreateQueryInstanceException
  {
    DBUquery dbu = new DBUquery(mcl_ts, mainGenerator.con);
    dbu.createPreparedStatement(stmt);
    dbu.setPreparedParameter(1, parId);
    dbu.setPreparedParameter(2, splId);
    dbu.setPreparedParameter(3, ogrId);

    dbu.createListFromResultSet(new DBUrowToObject()
    {
      //@Override
      public Object rowToObject(ResultSet rs) throws SQLException
      {
        String name = rs.getString("name");
        writeLn("<Outlet name=" + q(name) + "/>");
        return null;
      }
    });
```

and the error is 
 'class' or 'interface' expected at  });

Any ideas ? :)

Comment: You still use JDK 1.4?

Comment: Aren't you missing ```}``` at the end of method?

Comment: Yes :) core product library should compile with 1.4

Comment: HAd i missed an } , 1.7 would have shown the error too , in this code snippet i did not mark it

Comment: Could you give the line number?

Comment: Unless you've statically imported writeLn, there doesn't seem to be anything non-1.4 code involved.

Comment: Are you keeping `@Override` commented when you compile in 1.4?

Comment: The error is on the last line  --> }); the one due to override is a different error .. The current errror which I have mentioned in the question too is : 'Class' or 'interface' expected at });

Comment: Unless something is missing from the paste, it should not compile with 1.4 either; you have a missing closing curly brace at the end.

Comment: @fge : already answered to ur comment above , code snippet is not of entire class , so class closing brace missing

Comment: But here it is the closing bracket of the method which is missing, not of the class

Comment: user3291997: But you're also missing ```}``` at the end of the method! The one you have on the last line pairs with the anonymous class of ```DBUrowToObject```

Comment: This would be a whole lot easier if you actually provided us with the errors you're getting!

Comment: The error has been mentioned with the question   -->   'class' or 'interface' expected at });

Answer (score 0):

Check the pairs of curly braces. This error happens when there is something(possibly another `}`) after the closing brace of the class. Like this:

```
public class SomeClass {       
    private Object someMethod(){
    }
}
} <== This
```

Comment: OP explains this in the comments.

Comment: Had there been something fishy, the error would have been in 1.6 too. right ?

Comment: We don't see the complete class and this is exactly the case where you get ```'class' or 'interface' expected```

Comment: public class GTMoutletPlug extends GTMsectionGenerator
{
   public GTMoutletPlug(GTMpluggableGenerator aThis)
  {} 
  public void generateSection(long parId, long splId, long ogrId) throws DBUexecuteQueryException, DBUqueryParameterException, DBUcreateQueryInstanceException
  { dbu.createListFromResultSet(new DBUrowToObject()
    {
      //@Override
      public Object rowToObject(ResultSet rs) throws SQLException
      {
      
        return null;}});}}

Comment: user3291997: Edit: I've tried that and thought it's the reason, but I didn't notice that my IDE actually added one bracket when I was formatting the code.

Comment: I use Eclipse , i can see the last bracket closes the class , it highlights the first